# How to execute windows commands (ipconfig,netstat) with specific locale/codepage using python

Tags: python, windows, locale, codepages, ipconfig

I want to parse to output of windows commands such as `ipconfig`, `netstat`, `tasklist` 
etc. using python.

But certain part (Fixed) of output of these commands is returned based on current locale/codepage.

E.g. in `ipconfig` output

```
the string           IP Address..........:123.23.242.12
will be in chinese   IP 地址   ..........:123.23.242.12
```

or in other language depending on codepage.

Is there any way of executing commands such as `os.popen("ipconfig")` with specific locale/codepage setting.

1. I tried using locale module:
   `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"american_united states")`
   `locale.getlocale()` returns `"English_United States.1252"`
   but `os.system("chcp")` still returns old codepage: `936`
   and `os.popen("ifconfig")` returns strings in chinese.
2. `os.system("chcp 65001")`
   now `os.popen("ifconfig")` returns english strings but it clears all the previous output from console(may be it opens new console) which is not acceptable.

Is there any way of executing commands such as `os.popen("ipconfig")` with specific locale/codepage setting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this on my Win7 Professional... I seem to always get English strings. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7 only but installed chinese OS.

Comment: I believe your problem is in the fact that `setlocale` works on the local process and the new configuration is not propagated into the child process created by `popen`.
This is a rather tough one to deal with in Windows... In *nix systems you could set the environment in the command line: `PATH=$PATH:/home/foo ./my_program` or use `os.exec*` to leave the current environment to a child process, but I can't find a way to do the same with Windows.

Comment: I just end up use windows api to get all infomation i need.Parse command line output is not working in windows.